# PHP exceptions thrown in error handler not caught by exception handler

Tags: php, exception, plesk

I chose this title because I have the exact same problem as stated in here:
[PHP exceptions thrown in error handler are not caught by exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858022/php-exceptions-thrown-in-error-handler-are-not-caught-by-exception-handler)

The author accepted the answer which said he obviously was doing something wrong.
My error and exception handler were working fine that last two years, but now im facing the exactly same problem.
I did a code update and also a server update (Plesk 11.5 running, the PHP version should be the same and is 5.3.2). I checked my code for the error, but a test made it clear that this cant be the problem:

I wrote the following testfile:

```
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
   throw new Exception("this was an error");
}

function exceptionHandler($e) {
   echo 'exceptionHandler';
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler');
set_exception_handler('exceptionHandler');

// test one:
throw new Exception(); // outputs "exceptionHandler"

// test two - uncomment the first test of course! 
$test->blabla();
```

The second test should also output "exceptionHandler", **but it doesn't**!
The output is "Fatal error: Call to a member function blabla() on a non-object in ......./exeptiontest.php on line 0"

This problem drives me crazy at the moment. Any suggestions here? Any PHP settings that cause this?

Comment: You can't handle fatal errors with `set_error_handler()`

Comment: @SamDufel Yes I do. The problem is that the exception thrown in the error handler is not being caught by the exception handler..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (After reading your comment).

After an error handler has been executed program flow would went back to the expression after that where the error occurred. But it is unreliable to pass back program flow to a fatally failed script. That's why error handlers won't get called on fatal errors. The documentation says:

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.

As a workaround (depending on your needs), you may define a shutdown function using `register_shutdown_function()`.

---

**Original Answer** (It turned out that this was not the problem here)

You need to read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) of `set_exception_handler()` carefully, especially the code example:

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception');
echo "Not Executed\n";
```

Meaning in your case that `$test->blabla()` will never gets executed.

You might expect that the exception handler function works like a catch block, but that isn't the case. True is, that if an exception occurs and no catch block is defined, the program flow will take over to the exception handler which may gracefully shutdown the script -  but not more. If you want to handle exceptions the right way, use `try / catch`

---

Just to make it more clear: exception handlers behave different than error handlers. After returning from an exception handler the program will terminate while the program flow wents back to the expression after the error when returning from an error handler.

Comment: Did you miss my comment "// test two - uncomment the first test of course!"? I know that without it uncommented it will never be executed. The problem is something different

Comment: Then the answer is simple. PHP cannot catch fatal errors and it is unreliable to pass program flow back to the fatally failed script. You may define a shutdown function

Comment: btw, you could just have removed the first test from the example before posting here.. ;)

Comment: The test was to show that the exceptionHandler is being called. Fatal errors CAN be catched by set_error_handler(). Where do you have your information from?

Comment: Okay sorry, I dont want to go back to the program flow (that what you would normally understand with "catching the error", I just want to get my exception executed in the error handler and that works just fine on my XAMPP installation and it also did on the server the past two years.

Comment: Ok I gotta take that back. It seems that PHP did behave like this before :[ My bad! Thanks for your patient help!

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find anything in the changelog.. I hope I have explained well *why* this is impossible. A fatal error could be a syntax error for example. What should PHP do after that? No chance to recover this. (We should be happy that PHP devs didn't try to do so ;)